# How to Retrieve Image from server using Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need to retrieve image from server in vue js and laravel here is my code.

### Controller

```php
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return response()->json(["posts" => $posts]);
}
```

### Router

```php
Route::get('test','MasterController@index');
```

### Database

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

### Vue

```js
        data: function() {
            return {
                image: "",
                posts: [],
            };
        },
     showImage() {
                axios
                    .get("test")
                    .then(function(response) {
                        $test = this.posts = response.data.posts;
                        console.log($test);})
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
```

### Expected Image output

```
<img v-for="post in posts" :key="post.image" v-bind:scr="post.image">
```

Comment: So, what do you expect now? There is not even a question in your post.

Comment: I have changed to question

Comment: Have you tried running the code? If so does it work, if not what about it does not work? Are there any error messages etc? For us to help you need to provide us with more information.

Comment: I just run my code but it is not work that why I need your assist to check where my code is wrong

Comment: Where is `showImage()` invoked? Also, you should be able to pass `$posts` like `->json($posts)` in your index method. 

But as @GeorgeHanson has pointed out, you've listed your code here, but what you've failed to state is what the actual problem is?

Comment: I want to retrieve image in either database or public/image and displayed in the vue template,so I have tried to fetch image using <img v-for="post in posts" :key="post.image" v-bind:scr="post.image"> but it is not show any thing

Comment: I created this function created() {this.showImage(); } to invoke showimage()

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have posted, the `showImage()` method is not within the `methods` object of the Vue instance. Try putting the method into the `methods` object and see if that makes a difference.

```js
data: function() {
    return {
        image: "",
        posts: [],
    };
},
methods: {
    showImage() {
        axios.get("test").then(function(response) {
                $test = this.posts = response.data.posts;
                console.log($test);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrap the method in vue instance